# retornar para view que disparou o form em caso de algum erro! Nojde+Express

Tags: node.js, express.js, view

Bom dia pessoal, parece simples mas não consegui ainda por contra própria e nem encontrei pela net, só queria retornar para view que disparou o submit, tenho uma tela de cadastro simples... daí disparo a rota -> controller -> model. no controller tem os validadores, no caso de erro queria voltar pra o fomulário já preenchido!!  segue abaixo os trechos dos códigos :

Rota:

```
router.route('/cadastros').post(home.loggedIn, cadastrosController.salvaCadastro);
```

Controller:

```
exports.salvaCadastro = (req, res, next) => {

    let contract = new ValidationContract();
    contract.hasMinLen(req.body.nome_cadastros, 3, 'O nome deve conter pelo menos 3 caracteres');
    contract.isRequired(req.body.telefone1_cadastros, 'O telefone é obrigatório');
    contract.hasMinLen(req.body.telefone1_cadastros, 3, 'O telefone deve conter pelo menos 3 caracteres');

    // Se os dados forem inválidos
    if (!contract.isValid()) {
        req.flash('error', contract.errors());
        //req.flash('error', "Erro ao tentar pesquisar.", e);
        res.redirect('/cadastros');
        return;
    }


    modelCadastro.salvarCadastro(req.body)
        .then(idRegistro => {
            req.flash('success', 'Dados salvos com sucesso!');
         //   return false;
            return res.redirect('/cadastros');
        }).catch(e => {
            req.flash('error', "Erro ao tentar salvar os dados.", e);
            res.redirect('/cadastros');
      //      return false;
        });
}
```

Caso precise de mas informações favor solicitar!!!
Agradeço desde já pessoal!!

At +

Answer (score 0):

consegui exatamente agora (e por conta própria, parece óbvio mas apanhei um pouco heheh), para qm tiver a dúvida segue aí...

criei uma funcao que retorna o res.sender('view'....); passando o body, o req e o res para ele,

daí na funcao fica assim...

```
module.exports.renderCadastrosView = function (res, req, result, titulo) {

    return res.render('cadastros', {
        dados: result,
        session: req.session,
        idempresa: result.empresa_cadastros,
        titulo: titulo
    });

}
```

e eu á chamo dessa forma:

```
     if (!form.isValid()) {
         req.flash('error', contract.errors());
         Utils.renderCadastrosView(res, req, req.body,'Editando cadastro');
         return; 
}
```

por hora ta resolvido!!!
At+